# Java Scanner Limitations

Tags: java

I am reading through all files on my disk and searching for a string (using `java.util.Scanner`), so far I've limited this to just some basic file types like .html, .txt, .java. .css, and .cfg.  My question is if I don't limit it to those file types is there a chance I'll get some error trying to read an uncommon file type? Is there a file type that Scanner wont be able to read?

Comment: as long as it's plaintext you're fine but anything encoded like docx or pdf won't work obviously

Comment: Unrelated, but why? This functionality is duplicated by `strings` and `grep` from the shell. If you want to do full text search on files use something purpose-built that can handle non-text-based files.

Comment: What do you mean by "uncommon"? What kind of "error" would expect and why?

Comment: Yeah Dave, you're absolutely right, what im doing is pointless but this is part of an assignment i'm doing for a GUI class, essentially Im just seeing if I can go beyond the requirements of just those five file types.  And as for what I meant for "uncommon" I guess I was just trying to describe cases I wasn't prepared for when searching the entire disk for example another poster pointed out files like .exe or .zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "error".

Attempting to read a binary file through a Scanner is guaranteed to produce inconsistent results, since those binary files would use control characters which would prematurely terminate normal line processing.

It's also very, very easy to get an error trying to interpret a line of binary data as any other data type *besides* a `String`, since there's no way to guarantee that what you're reading could even *fit* in another data type.

So you are *well* advised to skip the non-text files.

Comment: That's very interesting, I hadn't thought of the ramifications of reading a binary file through a scanner, this is exactly what I wanted to know, thank you!!!